# Using AWS CloudFront in front of ALB for service running in AWS EKS is slower than directly using ALB

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudfront, amazon-eks

I have the following problem:
I have AWS EKS infrastructure with running microservices behind Application Load Balancer.
CloudFront is setup in front of that service and the odd thing is that if I contact that service, web-site directly, via LoadBalancer > running pod in EKS is far away fast than when I contact it via CloudFront > ALB > running pod.

Is anyone of you have at least roughtly idea why is that happening? Using CloudFront should be far away faster than reaching that service directly to ALB.

thanks

Comment: When you send a request to CloudFront, does it even respond or you get at timeout?

Comment: CF responds, but slowly